# How to get response status code in UIWebView when web view added to view programmatically in iOS Swift 3?

Tags: ios, http, swift3, webview, http-status-codes

I try to get **response status code** in **UIWebView**.
I tried like this:

```
func webViewDidFinishLoad(_ webView: UIWebView) {
    guard let request = webView.request else { return }
    let cachedUrlResponse = URLCache.shared.cachedResponse(for: request)
    let httpUrlResponse = cachedUrlResponse?.response as? HTTPURLResponse
    print("statusCode : \(String(describing:  httpUrlResponse?.statusCode))" )
}
```

and it's correct when i set *webView* in storyboard and *IBOutlet* that in controller. But in need to make a webView **programmatically** and did it.
But i can not get response status code with these codes.
Just get nil.
Please help me to fix it.

Comment: Can you post the code where you're creating the webview?  It could be that you're not setting the delegate correctly, or not retaining the webview, or something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

Declare your request globally. The request that you are loading in webView like

```
let  globalRequest = URLRequest(url: URL.init(string: "https://www.facebook.com")!, cachePolicy: URLRequest.CachePolicy.returnCacheDataElseLoad, timeoutInterval: 15.0)
```

and check for that request

```
let cachedUrlResponse = URLCache.shared.cachedResponse(for: globalRequest)
```

In webViewDidFinishLoad. That would work. The catch here I guess is URLRequest is now struct(value type) and the webView.request and globalRequest are two different things now. You can compare them and verify that.